# Ant (build.xml) equivalent to Eclipse's Build Path->Export?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, android-espresso

I have an Android test project using Espresso that I am attempting to build with Ant. I can build the test application just fine. Install it to the device and everything. The problem is, whenever I try to run the test with

> adb shell am instrument -w
>   com.test.package/com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner

I get this in my command prompt:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar:/data/app/test.apk:/data/app/myApp.apk
INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

And this in the logcat:

> E/AndroidRuntime(27558): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate instrumentation
>   ComponentInfo{com.avai.app.test.automate/com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
>   on path:
>   /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar:/data/app/test.apk:/data/app/myApp.apk

I can run the tests in Eclipse if I check the box next to my Espresso jar under `Configure Build Path->Order and Export`. I noticed that with this box unchecked I get the exact same error message as above.

**What I need to know is how to emulate Eclipse's behavior here with Ant?**

Here is a snippet from my build.xml file (mostly generated from `Export->Ant build files` in Eclipse:

`<path id="Android 4.4.2.libraryclasspath">
        ... (lots of jars) ...
    </path>
    <path id="AutomationTests.classpath">
        ... (more jars) ...
    </path>
    <path id="AutomationTests.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin/classes"/>
        <path refid="Android 4.4.2.libraryclasspath"/>
        <path refid="Android Private Libraries.libraryclasspath"/>
        <path refid="Android Dependencies.libraryclasspath"/>
        <pathelement location="../../android-test-kit/bin/espresso-standalone/espresso-1.1-bundled.jar"/>
    </path>`

    `<javac encoding="${java.encoding}" source="${java.source}"
        target="${java.target}"
        debug="true" extdirs="" includeantruntime="false"
        destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
        bootclasspathref="project.target.class.path"
        classpathref="project.javac.classpath">
            ...(stuff) ... 
    </javac>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing is caused by the third-party jar not being packaged inside the APK.
The default behaviour of the android ant build is that only the jars found in application project /libs folder are packaged into the apk.
Copy the espresso-1.1-bundled.jar to the /libs folder of the app project and you'll be fine.

Another thing to consider - you'll be better off generating the build.xml with Android tools as described here: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject